# Android MainActivity fails to launch

Tags: android

i have a MainActivity.java file like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText etword, etmean;
Button binsert;
Context c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    etword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWord);
    etmean = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMeaning);
    binsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bInsert);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

this file works well when i dont     setOnclickListener to my button. but when i do so the main activity fails to start. where is the problem???? i am setting up     onclicklistener like this....
    binsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            binsert.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
```

is shows an RuntimeException error and NullPointerException error. what am i missing?

Comment: post your log cat info

Comment: 08-15 10:53:36.319: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 10:53:36.319: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.babar.wordstock/com.babar.wordstock.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 10:53:36.319: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-15 10:53:36.319: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-15 10:53:36.319: E/AndroidRuntime(2541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content to the activity first and then initialize views.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // should come first
etword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWord); // then initialize views
etmean = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMeaning);
binsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bInsert);
}
```

You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. Your initiazlization fails. hence `NullPointerException`

Comment: can you describe the reason or post me a link containing the description regarding this problem?

Comment: @buet_baba also check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set content view.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); <--------------------------------see this line
    etword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWord);
    etmean = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMeaning);
    binsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bInsert);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView()` should be called as first. Also examining log output (logcat) helps in situations like this .